# How is a graphics object used with bufferStrategy in java?

Tags: java, swing, graphics, buffer, render

I'm trying to understand how the graphics class works in java, and while playing around with some code came across results that I can't explain myself.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferStrategy;

public class WindowTest extends Canvas{

    public WindowTest() {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("SOMETIMES I MAKE HUMOUR");

        frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 300));
        frame.pack();
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.add(this);

        render();
    }

    public void render() {
        this.createBufferStrategy(3);
        boolean running = true;

        /*BufferStrategy bs = this.getBufferStrategy();
        Graphics g = bs.getDrawGraphics();*/

        double frequency = 1;
        long lastTime = System.nanoTime();
        double delta = 0;
        double ns = 1000000000 / frequency;

        while (running) {

            long now = System.nanoTime();
            delta += (now - lastTime) / ns;
            lastTime = now;

            if(delta >= 1) {
                delta--;

                BufferStrategy bs = this.getBufferStrategy();
                Graphics g = bs.getDrawGraphics();

                g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
                g.fillRect(100, 50, 200, 200);

                g.dispose(); // without this game will eventually crash
                bs.show();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new WindowTest();
    }
}
```

If I use getDrawGraphics() and getBufferStrategy() in the while loop, the result is white frame -> white frame + green rect -> black. Then it continues as two white+green frames followed by 1 black frame. If instead I put those two methods outside the while loop, I expect the rectangle to appear only once. However, the result is white -> white+green followed by two black frames and one white+green.

Can anyone explain what is happening in the background to give these results? And why different background colors as well?

Comment: See docs for example: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/awt/image/BufferStrategy.html

Comment: When I run it either way I just get a green rect on a grey background, which is what I would expect.